# Get fully generated DOM elements inside iframe using selenium and phantomJS with python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, phantomjs

Ok, Im stuck. Im making a little web scraping python script using selenium and PhantomJS. The page that I working on has the data I want inside an iframe document that my web driver does not run.

```
<main Page Heads etc>

   <blah>

   <iframe 1 src="src1" ... etc etc>
    #document
      <tag>
      <tag>
      <iframe2 src="src2"><iframe2>
   <iframe1>

   <blah>

<end of webpage DOM>
```

I want to get the `src` of `iframe2`. I tried to run the `src1` URL through my webdriver but all I get out is the raw page html, not the loaded webpage elements, `iframe2` must be created by some script inside `iframe1`, but I can't get my webdriver to run the script.

Any ideas?

This what im doing to run the javascript on webpages to get the complied page DOM:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
self.driver.get(url)
page = self.driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a full page_source. In the case of iframe, you should use the following command: switch_to.frame(iframe_element), so you can get an element inside

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
self.driver.get(url)



WebDriverWait(self._driver, 50).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located
            ((By.XPATH,
              '//iframe[@id="iframegame"]'))
        )

iframe_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="iframegame"]')

self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_element)

tag = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tag')
```

And back again, you can get an outer element of iframe using the following command;

```
self.driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I tried but I got:```File "NBA/getLinks_nbastream_bilasport.py", line 112, in getIframeLink
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe1)
TypeError: Object of type 'Tag' is not JSON serializable```

Comment: Could you share your result?

Comment: Can you share the full html code or the link to the website?

Comment: This is what iframe1 looks like: ```<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="100%" id="iframegame" scrolling="no" src="http://bilasport.net/iframes/d/toronto-raptors-vs-boston-celtics-25247.html" width="100%"></iframe>
```  I cant put the whole thing because this comment box wont let me

Comment: When I "inspect" the page in chrome, iframe1 is full of other element, including iframe2. But I can still only get the source html with my script

Comment: I modified the code. Please pay attention to this line.
iframe_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="iframegame"]')

Comment: Ok i used you xpath command but now i get: ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//iframe[@id=\"iframegame\"]'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Content-Length":"112","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:35759","User-Agent":"selenium/3.141.0 (python linux)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"value\": \"//iframe[@id=\\\"iframegame\\\"]\", \"sessionId\": \"4d4cbee0-eaef-11ea-b52b-75a86e75ca55\"}","url":"/ele```

Comment: Is the tag name of the iframe  <iframe> or <iframe1>?

Comment: My browser is saying that the xpath for the first I frame element is ```"//*[@id='iframegame']"```, which is slightly different than the one in your suggested code. But i tried both and got the same result both times.

Comment: The tag name is just ```<iframe>```

Comment: Then you should insert wait function like this;

 WebDriverWait(self._driver, 50).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable
            ((By.XPATH,
              '//iframe[@id="iframegame"]'))
        )

Comment: Where do I put that exactly?

Comment: ```WebDriverWait(self._driver, 50).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable ((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@id="iframegame"]')) )
NameError: name 'WebDriverWait' is not defined```

Comment: oh i see, i will try

Comment: add this line;
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

Comment: It's because you didn't import WebDriverWait. Please take a look at my modified code.

Comment: Its timing out, ```File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```   Got WebdriverWait working, but it runs out of time.

Comment: Can you send the link?

Comment: ```http://bilasport.net/game/toronto-raptors-vs-boston-celtics-1.html```, that is the main page with both iframes inside of it

Comment: The code works well in my side. Could you test it once again?

Comment: Doesn't work. Still times out. Im actually running the code on an EC2 instance, i dont think that would make any difference but maybe it does somehow

Comment: Got it working! Must have been some typo somewhere in my code. Thanks a ton!